# Failure to connect to database (error :`com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`)

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

Greetings everyone and thank you for checking out my post. I am trying to connect my servlet with my database by using the Mysql jdbc driver. My **.jar** from mysql jdbc driver is in the folder **apache-tomcat-7.0.27/lib** .
MyServlet is a servlet and i have SQL.java in the same folder where connection must established.

```
private static Connection conn = null;
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
conn = (Connection) 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+"localhost:3306"+"/"+ "ergasia3", "root" , "spiros");`
```

Unfortunately, when i try to do this, i have an **error :**`com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` .

Here's my web.xml

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>WebApp01</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.srk.pkg.MyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyServlet.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <resource-ref>
    <description>database</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/ergasia3</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref> 
</web-app>
```

and now my context.xml

```
<Context path="/ergasia3" docBase="ergasia3"
debug="5" reloadable="true" crossContext="true">
  <Resource name="jdbc/ergasia3" auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
  user="root" password="spiros"
  driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ergasia3" 
  maxActive="15" maxIdle="3" /> 
</Context>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the .jar in Tomcat's lib, place it in your apps lib folder. All external .jars should keep here.

Comment: could you be more specific please?or could you give me a path?

Comment: YourProjectDir>WebContent>WEB_INF>lib.. then refresh the project. if it not works then Right click your project (in Eclipse IDE) & click properties. Then click JavaBuildPath & select Libraries tab to AddJARs (add MySQL connector here)

Comment: you may check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193311/jdbc-error-when-connecting-tomcat-5-5-to-sql-2008-what-am-i-missing) the same type of problem & the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put your jar under WEB-INF\lib

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution too sir/madam

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the database connection info already defined as a resource in tomcat instead of using the driver manager to create your connection it would be simpler to use the resource similarly to the following

```
// context used to create a datasource
Context dataSourceContext = new InitialContext();
// when you need a connection to the database
DataSource ds = (DataSource)dataSourceContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/ergasia3");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

Also, as previously stated by Soumyadip, you should be adding the mysql jdbc driver as an external jar to the web application and not in the tomcat lib directory because your application will be looking in its lib directory not the tomcat lib directory for the jar containing the mysql jdbc driver. How you do that depends upon what IDE you are using to develope the web app.

Comment: Thanks to your answer i was able to comprehend my mistake and face others that occured, thank you very much